# How to create a resizable SWT shell without title bar

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

I created a new shell using the following code:
Shell shell = new Shell( parent, SWT.RESIZE);

I am getting a resizable shell but with a small title bar on the top which I dont want.

[This is what I am getting after using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTWnq.png).

Is there any way to remove that title bar/border in the top but with retaining resizable functionality.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the window manager of the operating system you are using. On macOS just SWT.RESIZE does work but other systems may insist on some sort of title bar.

Comment: Is there any other way to create a window without the title bar but with resizable functionality in swt?